# mouseDoubleClickEvent пробивает по всем элементам, как исправить?

Tags: python, pyqt5, события

При двойном клике по QGraphicsPixmapItem, событие выполняется во всех QGraphicsPixmapItem лежащих под ним. Как исправить, что бы событие выполнялось только в том итеме, по которому был сделан двойной клик?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась на удивление просто.
Достаточно было удалить в переназначенной функции **QGraphicsPixmapItem** функцию **Super**

```
def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
```

`super().mouseDoubleClickEvent(event) # вот это удалил/закомментировал`

P.S. до сих пор не могу понять эту колдовскую функцию/метод. В каких случаях писать код перед ней, в каких после нее. И что произойдет если её вообще не прописывать.
В моем случае ничего не изменилось. **Если кто может объяснить в двух словах - напишите в комментариях, плз.**